# PyGST GStreamer corrupted file with google speech api

Tags: speech-recognition, gstreamer, recording, voice-recording, pygst

on a raspberry pi i am trying to record audio with gstreamer as a .flac or .wav file.

I want the audio file to be send to the inoffical google speech api server

But my gstreamer pipeline output as a wav

```
 gst-launch-0.10 -e  alsasrc device=hw:1 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw-int, depth=16, rate=16000, channels=1 ! wavenc ! filesink location= o.wav
```

or as a flac

```
 gst-launch-0.10 -e  alsasrc device=hw:1 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw-int, depth=16, rate=16000, channels=1 ! flacenc ! filesink location= o.flac
```

get always rejected.

Error: (wrong file format or wrong samplerate)

```
{"status":5,"id":"11e0fa5e371b2f0a1a87def81f8383bc-1","hypotheses":[]}
```

Normal recording with sox and encoding with ffmpeg or flac is working so i guess the output file from gstreamer is somehow corrupted or that iam missing something

**EDIT:**
 Pipeline running with -v http://hastebin.com/vovefeyewe.vbs added a queue after alsasrc
but still the same problem

**SOLVED**

Additional parameters solved the problem

```
 gst-launch-0.10 -e -v alsasrc device=hw:1 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! "audio/x-raw-int, rate=(int)16000, channels=(int)1, endianness=(int)1234, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, signed=(boolean)true, channles=(int)1" ! wavenc ! filesink location=g.wav
```

and If there is there no voice or only a random noise google will reject the file with the (wrong format error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add -v option in your pipeline and send the output?

Comment: try this pipeline but I am not sure that will works.   gst-launch-0.10 -e -v  alsasrc device=hw:1 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! "audio/x-raw-int, rate=(int)16000, channels=(int)1, endianness=(int)1234, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, signed=(boolean)true, channles=(int)1" ! wavenc ! filesink location=g.wav

Comment: It's really strange. I don't known why the pipeline doesn't works. It seems hardware problem. http://opencast.3480289.n2.nabble.com/Audio-recording-alsasrc-cant-record-audio-fast-enough-td6081621.html I have no more idea sorry

Comment: Yay it was working. The google speech api will report "status":5 if there is no voice or too much noise. Thank You!